# Opening+Reading With SQLite DB, But Getting Null Values?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm reading from a SQLite Database, which ostensibly opens correctly. However, I get a null pointer exception when I try to compare the titles of two objects I pull from it, which suggests something is off in how the read process is written. Sure enough -- when I comment the comparison part out (which would alphabetically sort the list of plants by name), the app will run, but all data fields in the view display as 'null'. I've looked over the code several times, and suppose I must be doing something logically wrong that another set of eyes might be able to detect.

Here's the Logcat output with stack trace:

```
[ 12-03 10:16:57.563  5898:0x1714 E/AndroidRuntime ]
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.xxx.wildedibles.full.intro.LoadingFragment$LoadingTask$1.compare(LoadingFragment.java:101)
    at net.xxx.wildedibles.full.intro.LoadingFragment$LoadingTask$1.compare(LoadingFragment.java:99)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:320)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:199)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2090)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1965)
    at net.xxx.wildedibles.full.intro.LoadingFragment$LoadingTask.doInBackground(LoadingFragment.java:99)
    at net.xxx.wildedibles.full.intro.LoadingFragment$LoadingTask.doInBackground(LoadingFragment.java:68)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
    ... 4 more
```

This is the relevant portion of LoadingFragment:

```
Plant plant = new Plant();
            GlobalData.plantArray = plant.populatePlantDataFromDB(mDbHelper);

            Collections.sort(GlobalData.plantArray , new Comparator<Plant>(){
                public int compare(Plant plant1, Plant plant2) {
                    return plant1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(plant2.getTitle());
                }
            });
```

And this is the relevant portion of the Plant class:

```
//Population method to read from DB
    public List<Plant> populatePlantDataFromDB(DBAdapter mDbHelper){

        List<Plant> plantsList = new ArrayList<Plant>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM plants";

        Cursor c = mDbHelper.getData(selectQuery);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list

        c.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    Plant plant = new Plant();
                    plant.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex("id"))));
                    plant.setTitle((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title"))));
         plant.setScientificName((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("scientificName"))));
                            //many, many fields
plantsList.add(plant);
            } while (c.moveToNext());


        c.close();
        return plantsList;      
    }
```

I'm sorry if the code spacing came in a bit wacky, but you can see what's going on here.

Many thanks for anything you can tell me!

Comment: What's in your `GlobalData.plantArray` when you debug?

Comment: looks like the column is empty in your database. did you checked that ?

Comment: Your code will fail if the plants table is empty.

Comment: Szymon -- GlobalData.plantArray is instantiated as null.

Comment: @nectaris you need to check for null value in the compare method

Comment: The plants table is not empty. I'm looking right at it in a SQL client. All plants have a defined title.

Answer (score 0):

a proper implementation of the compare method should fix the NullPointerException you are getting :

```
Collections.sort(GlobalData.plantArray , new Comparator<Plant>(){
            public int compare(Plant plant1, Plant plant2) {
                 if(plant1 == null || plant2 == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(plant1.getTitle()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(plant2.getTitle()) ){
                        return 0 ;
                 }
                return plant1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(plant2.getTitle());
            }
        });
```

and for the null values make sure the names of the columns are correct

Comment: Thank you for the fix, but I tried this and all the fields are still displaying 'null'. I think the problem is not the compare method, but something involving the actual reading of the database. I just don't know _where_...

Comment: @nectaris are you sure of the column names you are querying ? are you getting more than one row as a result but all values are null ?

Answer (score 0):

I would test:

```
 if (c == null) return null;
```

also, instead of

```
 getColumnIndex()
```

I would use:

```
 getColumnIndexOrThrow()
```

For testing, I would also override the `toString()` in your plants class and write there the id, title and scientificName. Then Log each plant object in the while loop where you get the database entries, using toString() and see what's missing if any.

I would also use constants (`public static final`) for the column names. It's so easy to type wrong.

Hope this helps you finding the problem.